# Which datatype can be used to create primary key variable in Hibernate/jpa?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

```java
@Entity
public class MyEntity {

@Id
@Column()
private String prKey;

  //....
}
```

which datatype can be used to create the primary key variable in Hibernate/JPA?

Answer (score 1):

According to the hibernate [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-simple):

> Simple identifiers map to a single basic attribute, and are denoted using the `javax.persistence.Id` annotation.
>
> According to JPA only the following types should be used as identifier attribute types:
>
> - any Java primitive type
> - any primitive wrapper type
> - java.lang.String
> - java.util.Date (TemporalType#DATE)
> - java.sql.Date
> - java.math.BigDecimal
> - java.math.BigInteger
>
> Any types used for identifier attributes beyond this list will not be portable.

Hibernate also support `java.util.UUID` as [identifier](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-generators-uuid).

Answer (score 0):

You can use java primitives, or primitive Wrappers for defining your Id type.
If you don't have any special requirements like composite keys, etc... the simplest solution is to use `Long` as key.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "ID")
private Long id;
```